# How to restrict the Donors to have limited functions of CiviCRM?

Tags: drupal, permissions, user-dashboard, user-interface

Here is what I have in mind...

- The donor needs to have access to submit credit card donation/events and View only his historic contributions.
- He needs to access his basic contact info and edit if necessary.
- All the link needs to be at one place for easy navigation. Links like PROFILE, HISTORIC CONTRIBUTION, Historic events, CONTRIBUTION PAGES, UPCOMING EVENTS
- No access to CiviCRM Menubar and any other pages by direct links
- No access to drupal Menubar

I was thinking to create a Drupal template page where I could place all the links, not sure if that makes any sense or even realistic?!

I was wondering did anyone have this kind of situation and if yes, how did you handle it? Or do you have any suggestions on how this can be achieved? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like most of what you want you can do via your CMS permissions to give them access to their Dashboard but not to CiviCRM itself